# Importing bitcoinj mnemonic into electrum or deriving private keys from mnemonic

Tags: bitcoinj, java, android, bitcoin-wallet-app

I am having a really hard time backing up my bitcoinj mnemonic and importing it somewhere else.

I am backing up the mnemonic like so:

```
    Wallet wallet = Wallet.createDeterministic(params, Script.ScriptType.P2WPKH);
    DeterministicSeed seed = wallet.getKeyChainSeed();
    System.out.println("seed: " + seed.toString());
    System.out.println("creation time: " + seed.getCreationTimeSeconds());
    System.out.println("mnemonicCode: " + Utils.SPACE_JOINER.join(seed.getMnemonicCode()));
```

This gives me: **cram approve decline tobacco truly giant remember author install dirt spare law**

The wallet dump for this wallet/mnemonic looks like this:

Keys:
Earliest creation time: 2020-09-10T23:01:55Z
Seed birthday:     1599778915  [2020-09-10T23:01:55Z]
Ouput script type: P2PKH
Key to watch:      xpub685v329L5UXezQQmCRgftKRud7hYHHR2U9RPCzRVwQNNWQuTHawgzBXD5RgAYLroJFiqTxEhF5jmbXJAWB341x8r3hdUFWfZd1Rh9uycNR3
Lookahead siz/thr: 100/33
addr:13ScJMSbxg6JYVaWNJAawZMaKW9KDdsz2H  hash160:1ac81dec190ab5981f5b8d9627136c806b013ff8  (M, root)
addr:18jGHhTXzKJcU1TqpMkozYQQBKHsnExT1H  hash160:54c71cd14809d8e4695d0ab8881b9c971c28d833  (M/0H, account)
addr:1HJbGGSZ42tG9nrTU6aGS2xJwCSEb6rKfg  hash160:b2d5af74fb0d34e5a072cf0514c9d0a6d949a699  (M/0H/0, external)
addr:19kEr724cNCXWgybTDPhNqN5rTVCcajdjD  hash160:5fee7381e26b401c7aca2d031e950aa7b6ff634d  (M/0H/1, internal)

Seed birthday:     1599778915  [2020-09-10T23:01:55Z]
Ouput script type: P2WPKH
Key to watch:      zpub6mkSeMVANqccjQLrtYC39g9eob95YG9cNvGFFBvXVgsT7mrJno4ChARSa1WWYdtuygHLDdkc5Bg6Lc45wx8xL2tSzgHsnzfqt4oSYR1Lecv
Lookahead siz/thr: 100/33
addr:bc1qrtypmmqep26es86m3ktzwymvsp4sz0lcurmxp8  hash160:1ac81dec190ab5981f5b8d9627136c806b013ff8  (M, root)
addr:bc1qppm602vv0ee29mndy37c3h5h4y753vyz82h5qt  hash160:0877a7a98c7e72a2ee6d247d88de97a93d48b082  (M/1H, account)
addr:bc1qz88ttzmmlr2w6d5wz40e9ejqxmr5avtmq2d6qq  hash160:11ceb58b7bf8d4ed368e155f92e64036c74eb17b  (M/1H/0, external)
addr:bc1q0v7emmg95uj738fnge70hwle23jdehpqxezqne  hash160:7b3d9ded05a725e89d33467cfbbbf95464dcdc20  (M/1H/1, internal)

**Now importing the bip39 mnemonic into electrum or the iancoleman site gives me completely different adressess no matter what derivation path I use. How can I import the mnemonic so that it creates the exact adresses as bitcoinj/android schildbach wallet? Or how else should I backup?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just restore as normal using electrum and on the screen where you have to enter the derivation path you set it to m/0' and choose legacy as the script type. Then create another wallet via file > new/restore for the p2wpkh addresses. This time choose native segwit as the wallet type and enter m/1' as the derivation path.

Comment: Sir, I am in your debt. Thank you very much.